# Error after moving WSUS DB from one server to another

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, wsus

I have a WSUS 3.2

[image]

Installed on a `Windows Server 2003 R2`. SQL Server 2005.

I want to move the WSUS DB from this server, to our new `SQL Server 2008 R2` on a new `Windows Server 2008 R2` Machine.

After following 2 guides

http://itechhawk.wordpress.com/2012/10/10/move-wsus-database-to-another-server/
 http://davehope.co.uk/Blog/moving-a-wsus-database/

I encounter an error:

[image]

I detached, copied, attached to the new server.

Comment: What's step-by-step? 1. - Back up, 2. - detach, 3. - restore, 4. - [***reconfigure***](http://davehope.co.uk/Blog/moving-a-wsus-database/).

Comment: Saariko, did you a) check that the database is actually working and database users are connected to server logins? b) reconfigure the WSUS instance to use the new server / instance name of the database server?

Comment: Attach logins to server role - DOH - missed that one. works, thanks. Post as answer to accept. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic procedure is

1. stop the WSUS service (`net stop WSUSService`)
2. Back up the source database (e.g. through the MS SQL Server Management Studio)
3. detach the source database
4. restore the previously taken backup at the destination
5. reconfigure the Database to correct user to login mappings and your WSUS server to point to the new database
6. start the WSUS service

In step 5., you would need to make sure that your WSUS server's computer account is created as a login at the SQL server instance and mapped to the respective database `dbo` user. You also would need to change the values of `SqlServerName` and `SqlInstanceIsRemote` in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\UpdateServices\Server\Setup` registry key to match your new configuration.

Needless to say, your SQL Server instance would need to be able to accept remote connections, support integrated Windows authentcation and the host running it has to be a member of the same domain as the WSUS server install host.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just had a similar issue after moving my remote SQL db for WSUS from one server to another.  Even though I modified the SqlServerName in the registry to update the new path that doesn't necessarily mean that WSUS will know the new location.

The additional step that was required was a command that looked similar to this:

```
WsusUtil.exe postinstall CONTENT_DIR=C:\WSUS SQL_INSTANCE_NAME=NEWSQLSERVER\InstanceName
```

`C:\WSUS` may be different for you as will the SQL instance name.
After this I was able to open the console